# Custom sheet in address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's what I want to do...
I have an excel with a bunch of sheets... let's name them A,B,C,D.
And another one where I get values from one of them depending what the user enters in one cell.
So... to get a value from a sheet I use the following formula

```
='[file.xls]A'!$I$15
```

What I want to do... is if an user enters value B in a specific cell to have the formula changed to:

```
='[file.xls]B'!$I$15
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only INDIRECTly reference a workbook that is open.  If you are not going to open the external reference document, then you will need to install additional functionality into your Excel.

The ADD-IN is called MoreFunc...read all about it here:
***http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/***

Download and install it from here:
***http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/30...-10423159.html***

Go into **TOOLS > ADDINS** and activate MoreFunc.

Now you have many, many new functions available to you. Any place you used INDIRECT, now use INDIRECT.EXT instead and it will work on closed workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Build the address string, and then use `INDIRECT` to retrieve its value.
e.g: if the sheet sheet name is in A1, then your formula could be something like
`=INDIRECT("'[file.xls]" & A1 & "'!$I$15")`

Comment: Probably because there is a path to the file too? something like \\:abc.abc.abc\abcd\efgh\ ? Any ideas?

Comment: @Andrei. just build your formula in normal Excel sheet, then try to replicate that string (except the initial = ) as an argument for INDIRECT.